# Adding new bib files by default to the current library

Tags: bibtex, jabref

I am using JabRef for managing my citation bib files. When I am trying to drag and drop new bib file into the current library in JabRef, JabRef automatically creates new library. Is there is a way to make JabRef add new bibs files to the already opened library when dragging and drop new bib file?

Comment: I think there is no such a option. Just use `Ctrl+I`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can not drag and drop a bib file into a current library which is open in JabRef. Instead you can open the bib file with a text editor, select the whole text (bib entries) and then drag it into JabRef (which may not be a proper solution for you).

The other way is to use *Import into current library (Ctrl+I)* in file menu.

Comment: Thanks, I know about (Ctrl+I), yet it is not what I am looking for. Actually, I am just looking for quick way (drag and drop) to import bib files into the current library.

Answer (score 0):

I also want that. What I'm doing now is: open a bib file or more often import it from a journal, and then copy the reference from the "new library" to my main library (just highlight the reference Ctrl+C, and Ctrl+V into my main library). I call it manually append, and it's not elegant at all.